# node.js error: throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer')

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner in Node.js and I'm not able to find what I did wrong. Please follow the link below to see codes.

```
Server has started...
Request for /start received.
About to route a request for /start
Request Handler 'start' was called.
_http_outgoing.js:645
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:620:10)
    at Server.onRequest (H:\Docs\Codes\Web\nodejs beginner\server.js:11:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:602:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
```

Link to my code:
https://github.com/PsYcO-kk/nodejs-beginner

Comment: try in router.js return handle[pathname](); instead of simply call

Comment: In the future you should try to isolate the problem to a specific part of the code, and copy paste that in the question. You'll get better responses that way, instead of linking to a github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In router.js you have:

```
if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
    handle[pathname]();
  }
```

but you are not returning `handle[pathname]();`

It works correctly like this:

```
if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
    return handle[pathname]();
  }
```

Try to use eslint when you're programming, this would have warned you of the missing return statement.